# Plaster & Non-Standard Wire Mesh Patching

Tags: plaster, old-house

Had some electrical work done leaving holes in walls that need to be patched.

The plaster and wire mesh in my house (built in 1920) does not appear to be the typical chicken wire mesh that most search results yield. My wires appear to be about 2 inches or so apart in a grid like fashion and placed under that was some sort of black fabric. The combination of the large spaced wires and fabric are what looks like was used to originally hold the plaster.

My plan is to mix Green Top and Plaster so it is relatively stiff and just go right over everything. My concern is on the deep holes I will need something to catch and hold this mixture.

If had typical wire mesh or lath behind the plaster I wouldn't be posting this as there are plenty of tutorials here and elsewhere on how to patch in those instances.

Has anyone encountered this before and know the correct way to patch this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Technically that cable would need protection, being so close to the surface. I'd have probably cut larger openings, run the cable through the framing as normal, and put in drywall patches. Not sure what to suggest now.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll be sure to keep cable protection in mind.

Comment: I agree, not good or legal to bury romex in the plaster.

Comment: "Hey sweetie, how did you get electrocuted?"... "I can't answer because I was electrocuted while hanging up this picture of our kids..."

Comment: Now that we have shamed you, we can help you. In both pictures it seems you could easily just jam some paper or cardboard in there, then use setting plaster (sets fast and hard, like Fixall or Water Putty) as a base layer, these plasters tend to expand and hold fast when setting. Then just use your finish plaster over that.

Comment: Really like the cardboard idea. Got a bunch in an cut to shape. What about structolite as a base coat and green top as a top coat? Asking because it's what I have on hand. If not it's a quick trip to store. I think I have a way forward now but man if I'm still not curious to how/why it was done originally.